# Не могу распарсить динамический сайт, если точнее при переходе на страницу с json, дает ошибку 405

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, web-scraping

Сайт https://mangalib.me/manga-list

В браузере Chrome в **developer tools** во вкладке **Network** мне удалось найти `list` запрос, который на выходе в вкладке **Response** выдает мне [json](/questions/tagged/json).

Но когда я пробую перейти на [страницу](https://mangalib.me/api/list) из запроса, то получаю ошибку **405**.

```console
Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed".

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred.
We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

Получаю вот это. Подскажите пожалуйста как парсить на [python](/questions/tagged/python), подобные сайты

Comment: реферер, ксрф или там список дается в ответ на пост

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста как парсить на python, подобные сайты

Что же, давай попробую объяснить.

То на что ты ссылаешься из увиденного в **developer console** обращается с токенами [csrf](/questions/tagged/csrf) и `XSRF`. Без них, мой друг, ничего у тебя не выйдет.
Брать их надо в разных местах, один лежит в куках, другой надо вытягивать с страницы, то бишь парсить, и проще всего это сделать с [beautiful-soup](/questions/tagged/beautiful-soup).

```python
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_mangas(url, sesseion, csrf, xsrf, page=1):
    headers = {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf,
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': xsrf
    }
    data = { "page": page }
    r = sesseion.post(url+'/api/list', headers=headers, json=data)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        r.raise_for_status()
    return json.loads(r.text)

url = r'https://mangalib.me'

s = requests.Session()
s.get(url)
xsrf = s.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']

r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
csrf = soup.find('meta', {'name': '_token'})['content']

mangas = get_mangas(url, s, csrf, xsrf)
pprint(mangas, depth=2)
```

###### Вывод:

```console
{'items': {'current_page': 1,
           'data': [...],
           'first_page_url': 'http://mangalib.me/manga-list?page=1',
           'from': 1,
           'next_page_url': 'http://mangalib.me/manga-list?page=2',
           'path': 'http://mangalib.me/manga-list',
           'per_page': 60,
           'prev_page_url': None,
           'to': 60}}
```

Работает.
Что дальше с этим можно сделать? Можно в [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) запихнуть.

#### Собираем в таблицу

```python
df = None
page = 0
while(mangas['items']['next_page_url'] != None):
    page+=1
    mangas = get_mangas(url, s, csrf, xsrf, page)
    for manga in mangas['items']['data']:
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(manga))
        temp_df['page'] = mangas['items']['current_page']
        if type(df) == type(None):
            df = temp_df
        else:
            df = pd.concat([df, temp_df])
```

У меня этот блок отработал довольно шустро, всего **10.9** секунд.
По итогу имеем **DataFrame** с 1800 записями. Осталось их причесать.

##### Обработка таблицы

Итак, какие колонки у нас есть?
`df.dtypes`

| Имя колонки | Тип данных |
| --- | --- |
| id | int64 |
| name | object |
| eng_name | object |
| rus_name | object |
| cover | object |
| slug | object |
| type_id | int64 |
| created_at | object |
| updated_at | object |
| site | int64 |
| type | object |
| modelType | object |
| coverImage | object |
| coverImageThumbnail | object |
| href | object |
| title_status_id | object |
| covers.default | object |
| covers.thumbnail | object |
| page | int64 |

1. Из `id` можно сделать индекс, там уникальные ключи
   `df = df.set_index('id')`
2. Дальше имеет смысл убрать бесполезные колонки. Например, те, в которых только одно уникальное значение
   `df.nunique()[lambda x : x < 2].index.to_list()`
   На выходе:
   ['site', 'modelType', 'title_status_id']
3. Можем убедиться, что в них нет ничего интересного:
   `for i in df.nunique()[lambda x : x < 2].index.to_list(): print(df[i].unique())`
   На выходе:

   - `[1]`
   - `['manga']`
   - `[None]`
4. Смело убираем. Также я бы убрал колонки содержащие `http` и `uploads`, т.е. содержащие полные и относительные ссылки. Это балласт. В таблице достаточно информации, чтобы их обратно пересобрать, но об этом позже.
   Тут, впрочем, на вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные, если тебе удобно иметь колонки с полными ссылками, оставляй их.

```python
df = df.drop(columns=df.nunique()[lambda x : x < 2].index.to_list())
df = df.drop(columns=df.iloc[0][df.iloc[0].str.contains('http|/uploads/', na=False)].index.to_list())
```

5. Балласт убрали, приведём колонки с временем к `datetime`, сейчас они просто объект.

```python
for col in df.columns[6:8]:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

6. В конце русифицируем таблицу и отсортируем колонки:

```python
cols = ['Названия.Название','Названия.English','Названия.Русское','slug.Обложка',
        'slug.Манга','Тип.id','Время.Создано','Время.Загружено','Тип.Тип','.Страница']
df.columns = cols
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns.str.split('.',expand=True))
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
df
```

###### Вывод:

[image: Результирующая таблица]

##### Как пересобрать ссылки

```python
url+'/'+df[('slug','Манга')]
url+'/uploads/cover/'+df[('slug','Манга')]+'/cover/'+df[('slug','Обложка')]+'_250x350.jpg'
url+'/uploads/cover/'+df[('slug','Манга')]+'/cover/'+df[('slug','Обложка')]+'_thumb.jpg'
```

Либо просто выводишь в консоль, либо добавляешь в новую колонку. Но в новую колонку нет необходимости добавлять, достаточно просто не убирать изначальные столбцы из **DataFrame**.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141188/discussion-on-answer-by-dimithras-------).