# Получаю пустой массив из bs4

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Пытаюсь спарсить данные из сайта, но прилетает пустой массив, это какая то защита или не пойму. Код приложен

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://tofunft.com/ru/collection/iguverse-nft/activities?category=listing'
ua = UserAgent()
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.chrome}

responce = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, "html.parser")
find_data = soup.find_all('div', __class="chakra-stack")

print(find_data)
```

Comment: на сайте похоже динамическая загрузка. используйте selenium

Comment: @Prog [tag:selenium] создан для автоматизации тестов, а не парсинга. Вредный совет. Есть [tag:scrapy] и прочие для динамических страниц.

Comment: Что именно достать хочешь с сайта?

Comment: @DiMithras хотел достать нижний список, в других случаях получаю огромный скрипт из js, в принципе там есть данные, но разобрать для меня сложно.

Comment: @Аске ясно, сейчас отвечу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Защита на сайте есть, но такая же как и эти ваши NFT, бесполезная. Можешь открыть страницу в Tor, чтобы грузилась помедленнее, и посмотреть что там происходит.

Да, это защита от cloudflare, которая проверяет cookies и JS. Но на любую старуху бывает проруха, тем более что подобной защите уже много лет, соответственно есть и решения.

[Cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) весит всего 98 kB, не грузит ресурсы как Selenium, который вместе с нужными данными подгрузит ещё кучу всякого непотребства, довольно лёгок в использовании. По сути надстройка над requests и requests_toolbelt.

```python
import cloudscraper
s = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
url = r'https://tofunft.com/_next/data/U1Z9uAYluX_zw7t7_5z3D/ru/collection/iguverse-nft/activities.json'
params = {
    'category':'listing',
    'slug':'iguverse-nft'
}
# params['page'] = 2
j = s.get(url, params=params).json()
for i in j['pageProps']['data']['searchResp']['data']:
    print(i['nft']['meta']['name'])
```

###### Output:

```
Office Rat
Warrior
Dumka
Chester
King
King
Bonya
Swiper Boy
Laemanctus White
Diego
Diego
Ciffer
Pink Floyd
Laemanctus White
Swiper Boy
Kitpy
Diego
Red Bull
Leri
Cat
```

Защита тут слабая, даже headers не требуется, насиловать сайт можно сколько угодно.
А это значит, что собираешь из [json](/questions/tagged/json) необходимые тебе данные, засовываешь всё в цикл, где инкрементируешь `page` и собираешь весь этот бардак в DataFrame. Как это делать можно подсмотреть в другом моём ответе:
[Не могу распарсить динамический сайт, если точнее при переходе на страницу с json, дает ошибку 405](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1474580/531666)

### Совет

> Пытаюсь спарсить данные из сайта, но прилетает пустой массив, это какая то защита или не пойму

По твоему коду, у тебя не просто пустой массив. Посмотри что тебе выдаёт `responce.status_code` (response через S пишется).

Божечки, да там же `403`, понятное дело у тебя массив пустой.

---

## Update

Пересмотрел свой ответ после очередного голоса, понял, что `import json`, в общем-то, лишний, он и так есть в качестве метода в [requests](/questions/tagged/requests). Убрал лишнее в изначальном ответе. Попробовал перезапустить код, а там **ошибка 404**.
Забавно, сайт поменялся, немного усложнил нам жизнь. Собственно, что поменялось? **Json** больше не доступен в вкладке Network, теперь он встроен в страницу в качестве скрипта. Создатели сайта читают SO? Ну ок‥ не знаю зачем они так сделали, чтобы успешно выполнить код у себя, придётся его немного изменить, а именно, попарсить страницу и вытянуть [json](/questions/tagged/json) из [html](/questions/tagged/html):

```python
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
s = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10,   browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0',})
url = r'https://tofunft.com/ru/collection/iguverse-nft/activities'
params = {
    'category':'listing',
    'slug':'iguverse-nft'
}
r = s.get(url, params=params)
soup = BS(r.content, 'lxml')
j = json.loads(soup.find('script', id='__NEXT_DATA__').text)
for i in j['props']['pageProps']['data']['searchResp']['data']:
    print(i['nft']['meta']['name'])
```

###### Вывод:

```
[unusual] Moxito
[starter] BYSINKA
[common] Borya
[common] Huilushechka
[uncommon] Naive
[uncommon] Naive
[uncommon] mishania
[uncommon] mishania
[uncommon] Otan
[uncommon] Otan
[uncommon] Dinero
[uncommon] Dinero
[uncommon] Kralya
[uncommon] Kralya
[uncommon] Billy
[uncommon] Billy
[uncommon] DjTyzik
[uncommon] DjTyzik
[uncommon] Tubzik
[uncommon] Tubzik
```

Как видно, сам **json** тоже немного поменялся, добавился новый ключ верхнего уровня. В целом, не страшно, но зачем так делать я не понимаю

Comment: `cloudscraper` работает :)

Comment: @gil9red а главное весит почти ничего и по сути позволяет дальше пользоваться requests без драйверов 

Comment: Да вы гений, я польщён. Кстати статус приходит 200, по этому я был в ступоре

Comment: @Аске ухх ты… странно. Тогда я очень советую дополнить вопрос тем что выдаёт `responce.text` в отдельном блоке, тем кто попадёт на данный вопрос будет крайне полезно!