# Парсинг сайтов, защищенных cloudfare

Tags: python, парсер, cloudflare

Написал скриптец на питоне, использую undetected chrome browser библиотеку. На сайт заходит, проходит капчу, все тип-топ вроде, но как только запускается скрипт сбора инфы - сразу обрубает. Пробовал разные методы: bs4, scrapy. В общем сколько ни долбился я с этим cloudflare, так ничего и не вышло. Может кто подсказать хотя бы в каком направлении инфу искать? Ютуб и ру и инглиш сегмент ответа не дают. Гугл тоже не помог. Все, что находил по давности год и более и на данный момент не работает, по крайней мере у меня.

Comment: Selenium - можно попробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было бы проще, конечно, если бы вы указали сайт, и можно было попробовать.
Но, тем не менее, оформлю в ответ. Потому что:

> В общем сколько ни долбился я с этим **cloudflare**, так ничего и не вышло.

Для cloudflare есть замечательная библиотека [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) и мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1478650/531666) по этой библиотеке с схожей проблемой. Пробуйте, защита не менялась уже какой год и библиотека всегда выручала.

И, пожалуйста, изучите [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), добавляйте код, или хотя бы источник, и у вас не будет **-3** в рейтинге.